# Kotlin cannot create an instance of ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, runtimeexception, androidx

I've been getting the following error against my ViewModel:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cryptpass_kt/com.example.cryptpass_kt.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.cryptpass_kt.EntryViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1609)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6703)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.cryptpass_kt.EntryViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:238)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130)
        at com.example.cryptpass_kt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2806)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1609) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6703) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:230)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130) 
        at com.example.cryptpass_kt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:40) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2806) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1609) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6703) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769) 
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property allEntries has not been initialized
        at com.example.cryptpass_kt.EntryRepository.getAllEntries(EntryRepository.kt:9)
        at com.example.cryptpass_kt.EntryViewModel.<init>(EntryViewModel.kt:11)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:230) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130) 
        at com.example.cryptpass_kt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:40) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2806) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1609) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6703) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

The error points to 3 locations in my app.  The first one being the initiation of the `viewModel` object in my `MainActivity.kt` class' `onCreate()` method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EntryViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.allEntries.observe(this, Observer { entries -> adapter.submitList(entries) })

        ...
    }
```

The 2ndpoint is the `LiveData` object in my repository class:

```
class EntryRepository(application: Application) {
    private val entryDAO: EntryDAO
    lateinit var allEntries: LiveData<List<Entry>>

    ...
    }
```

And the 3rd point is the repository object inside the `ViewModel`:

```
class EntryViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository: EntryRepository = EntryRepository(application)
    val allEntries: LiveData<List<Entry>>

    init {allEntries = repository.allEntries }

    fun insert(entry: Entry) {repository.insert(entry)}

    fun update(entry: Entry) {repository.update(entry)}

    fun delete(entry: Entry) {repository.update(entry)}

    fun deleteAll() {repository.deleteAllEntries()}
}
```

The first time I had this error, I was told on S/O that it was due the fact that I had some implementations in my gradle file that were not AnroidX compatible.  After fixing that, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property allEntries has not been initialized
```

In `EntryViewModel`, you have this line:

```
init {allEntries = repository.allEntries }
```

You are referencing the `allEntries` property of the `EntryRepository`. That is defined as `lateinit`:

```
lateinit var allEntries: LiveData<List<Entry>>
```

The error is telling you that you have not assigned a value to `allEntries` before trying to reference it. If you are going to use `lateinit` on a visible (non-`private`) property, you need to ensure that you assign a value to it before any other object can try using that property.